# "second-hand X smoker" vs "second-hand smoker of"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one sounds more natural to a native English speaker?

Example:

> I thought about the air quality of my country and decided I was a
>   **second-hand traffic fumes and industrial gas smoker.**
>
> I thought about the air quality of my country and decided I was a
>   **second-hand smoker of traffic fumes and industrial waste gas.**

Comment: In Britain we sell *second-hand cars* but do not talk about *second-hand smoke*. We do, however, talk of *passive smokers*, and *passive smoking*. But of your two examples I prefer the second.

Comment: I think the second example sounds better, especially because in this case the phrase taking the place of "X" is fairly long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ears (American) both sound off. A person is not usually referred to as a "second-hand smoker", rather people are victims of "second-hand smoke."

For example, I might use

"...I was a victim of **second-hand traffic smoke and industrial waste gas.**"

By the very nature of "second-hand" smoking, it is not something that a person would be considered to be actively doing. For this reason, I think, "second-hand smoker" is uncommon. It puts the blame/action on the person who is passively inhaling the smoke.